# Horizontal boxplot using seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset of 30 students with 7 features each that represent skills (art, mathematics, etc). After applying k-means algorithm, these students were divided in 3 clusters. 0, 1, 2 are the labels:

```
Id CCL CMCT CD CPAA CSC SIE CEC labels
1    2    5  4  5.5   6 2.5   5      0
etc
```

I would like to represent it in 3 different boxplots, one for each cluster. I thought that it would be good to have an horizontal plot where "y" was the seven skills and "x" was the qualification. I am not sure how to achieve this with sns.boxplot().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you would want to **start by melting your dataframe** because it is currently in wide format and Seaborn [prefers long or tidy format](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html).

**Then you can use `sns.catplot()`** so that you have three plots, instead of one. From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

> Use catplot() to combine a boxplot() and a FacetGrid. This allows
> grouping within additional categorical variables. Using catplot() is
> safer than using FacetGrid directly, as it ensures synchronization of
> variable order across facets:

```
### Make dummy dataframe
id = np.arange(1,10,1)
np.random.seed(0)
CCL = list(np.random.randint(5, size=len(id)))
CMCT = list(np.random.randint(8, size=len(id)))
CD = list(np.random.randint(5, size=len(id)))
CPAA = list(np.random.randint(9, size=len(id)))
CSC = list(np.random.randint(12, size=len(id)))
SIE = list(np.random.randint(5, size=len(id)))
CEC = list(np.random.randint(7, size=len(id)))
labels = list(np.random.randint(3, size=len(id)))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id, CCL, CMCT, CD, CPAA, CSC, SIE, CEC, labels)), 
    columns =['id', 'CCL', 'CMCT', 'CD', 'CPAA', 'CSC', 'SIE', 'CEC', 'labels']
    )
print(df)
```

[image]

```
### Now melt and plot
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'labels'], 
            value_vars=['CCL', 'CMCT', 'CD', 'CPAA', 'CSC', 'SIE', 'CEC']
            )
print(df_melt)

sns.catplot(data=df_melt, x='value', y='variable', col='labels', kind='box')
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It worked but how can I show also the points? combined with stripplot

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68616135/seaborn-boxplot-with-dataframe-containting-quantiles